# THREE.js (R75) Rules about Declaring Attributes and Matrices when using Multiple Vertex Shaders

Tags: three.js, shader

I have encountered problems when using two shader materials which each use a different pair of vertex & fragment shaders and go with a different (customized) buffer geometry.  Both geometries use the same attribute names such as position, normal, uv and color.

I can get both shaders to work either on their own or at the same time.
But the program is sensitive to declarations of attributes and matrices.  I had to do trial and error to find which declarations to retain and which ones to comment out.

Here is the shader code I use to get the two shader materials working at the same time ( Pair1 =  vertexShader01 + fragmentShader01 and Pair2 = vertexShader03    + fragmentShader03 ).

```
<script id="vertexShader01" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

// HEADER01 //
//... Not a problem for header to be inactive if the shader is not used.
//...  if two shader materials active then this header must be active.
//...  if one shader material active and one defined but not active then this header must also be active.

    precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; 
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;              
    attribute vec3 position;
    attribute vec4 color;
    attribute vec3 normal; 
////            
    uniform float uTime;    
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec2 vUv; 
    void main() 
    {
        vPosition = position;
        vColor = color;
        vec3 NewPosition = vPosition;
        NewPosition = vPosition + 2.0 * normal * ( 1.0 + sin( uTime/10.0 ));
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( NewPosition, 1.0 ) ;
    }
</script>
<script id="fragmentShader01" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
    uniform float uTime;
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    varying vec4 vColor;            
    void main() 
    {
        vec4 color = vec4( vColor );
        color.r += sin( vPosition.x * 10.0 + uTime ) * 0.2; //... makes (position & time)dependent waves of color variation.
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
</script>

<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<script id="vertexShader03" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
// HEADER03 //
    //... Works OK without any of these active when one or two shader-pairs.

    //precision mediump float;
    //precision mediump int;            
    //uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; // optional
    //uniform mat4 projectionMatrix; // optional                        
    // *** Enabling any of these attributes KILLS the shader!!! ?????? ***
    //... attribute values are only defined or changed in javascript

    //attribute vec3 position;  //... 3 values per vertex
    //attribute vec2 uv;        //... 2 values per vertex
    //attribute vec4 color;     //... 4 values per vertex
    //attribute vec3 normal;    //... 3 values per vertex; 

////        
    uniform float uTime;
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec2 vUv;           
    void main() 
    {
        vPosition = position; 
        vUv = uv;
        //... Sinusoidal expand and contract, amplitude is uniform
        vec3 NewPosition = vPosition + 2.0 * normal * ( 1.0 + sin( uTime/10.0 ));       
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( NewPosition, 1.0 );        
    } 
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader03" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
    uniform sampler2D baseTexture;
    varying vec2 vUv; 
    void main() {   gl_FragColor = texture2D( baseTexture, vUv );  }
</script>
```

If I activate the "Header 03" declarations (by uncommenting them) the following errors are logged:-

```
three.js:29438 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders ERROR: 0:48: 'modelViewMatrix' : redefinition 
ERROR: 0:49: 'projectionMatrix' : redefinition 
ERROR: 0:55: 'position' : redefinition 
ERROR: 0:56: 'uv' : redefinition 
ERROR: 0:58: 'normal' : redefinition
```

This may seem to suggest "well you just need to do one set of declarations!"

However if I activate the Header03 declarations but comment out the Header01 declarations then there are similar errors to those above.  This suggest that the order of definition or the order of usage might be significant.

So anyway I am wondering if there are some known rules-of-thumb about how/where/when/why to do declarations of attributes and matrices in situations like this (where the same attribute names and matrix names are being used by different shader materials).

I have looked at the [relevant shader documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial) but it does not resolve my ignorance here.

======================================================================

UPDATE

Switched to using just RawShaderMaterial (instead of ShaderMaterial or RawShaderMaterial).

All vertex shaders amended to have header declarations consisting of:-

```
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; 
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix; 
attribute vec3 position;    //... 3 values per vertex.
attribute vec2 uv;          //... 2 values per vertex.
attribute vec4 color;       //... 4 values per vertex.
attribute vec3 normal;      //... 3 values per vertex.
```

(Attributes to be declared here are those required in the shader code, and present in the buffer as attributes.)

also, all fragment shaders have to include the following header code:-

```
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
```

Then all the shader code blocks will compile OK and the buffer-objects which use them will plot properly.

The source codes are here [ShaderMaterial](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/ShaderMaterial.js) and here [RawShadermaterial](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/RawShaderMaterial.js).  I cannot say that I understand why this works except that the documentation for RawShaderMaterial states

```
This class works just like ShaderMaterial, 
except that definitions of built-in uniforms and attributes 
are not automatically prepended to the GLSL shader code.
```

Comment: Try `RawShaderMaterial`.

Comment: Thanks yet again, that works fine.  Now every shader code has been amended to include essential "header" declarations, as described in the UPDATE to my quesiton.

Comment: Im confused by this question. Why are you adding those uniforms manually? ShaderMaterial will declare those for you, since they are common, and most likely needed in a shader? 
Shadermaterial gives you some common uniforms,
Rawshadermaterial wont do anything for you, hence you only declare your header once. Of course it's complaining about redefinition. Take a look at the shader string when your browser throws an error and you will see the entire shader.

Comment: @pailhead I'm a dummy regarding shaders. I was using a ShaderMaterial and a RawShaderMaterial in the same app but kept getting errors.  Since switching to only using RawShaderMaterial and including full declarations the errors have ceased.

Comment: yes but there is no need to do that for what you are doing. Try going back to the shader material, but omit all these 'default' uniforms, declare your other uniforms where you want them. You do need to have just one set of declarations. You cannot declare the same variables that three already declares for you. You dont need to declare the uniforms from ShaderMaterial yourself in the RawShaderMaterial (although you can). 

You are probably trying to do something outside of shaders that is confusing you.

Comment: to reiterate, creating a THREE.ShaderMaterial({vertexShader: myVs}) will include the header from your question automagically. If you create a buffer geometry with a buffer attribute named 'position', just call it in ShaderMaterials vertex shader and it will be there. If its not youre doing something wrong setting that up.

Comment: @pailhead Thanks for your suggestions. But my app is working OK now using two RawShaderMaterial materials, each with the 2 * precision statements (in vertext and fragment shader code) and the 2 * uniform mat4 statements (in the vertex shader code). I can tailor the attributes declarations as required to match whichever attributes in my CUSTOM buffers I will be accessing in the shader.  I understand these rules now.   To use ShaderMaterial - which assumes STANDARD buffer attributes - doesn't offer me anything better, or so it seems to me.